# Unable to Edit Any Content Query Web Parts in Single Site Collection

Tags: 2010, content-query-web-part, content-type-hub

When attempting to edit any Content Query Web Part on any page within one particular site collection (by clicking "Edit Web Part"), SharePoint displays a generic "An unexpected error has occurred" message.  When tracing the issue, the logs have the following runtime error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Invalid field name.
{94f89715-e097-4e8b-ba79-ea02aa8b7adb} http://intranet     

at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.GetFieldById(Guid fieldId,
Boolean bThrowException)      at
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.get_Item(Guid id)      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryToolPart.PopulateFieldsFromWeb(SPWeb web)      at
Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryToolPart.populateData()
at
Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryToolPart.populateCBQControls()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryToolPart.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()      at
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()      at
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()      at
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()      at
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()      at
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()      at
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()      at
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

I've tried searching for the Invalid Field ID by GUID using PowerShell, but the field doesn't exist by that GUID (as far as I can tell).

The only change that the site collection administrator claims to have performed was changing the site collection into a "Content Type Hub" - could this potentially have caused the issues described?  If so, is there a solution to fix it?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

EDIT: I've noticed that I cannot see the standard out-of-the-box content types in the site settings (custom types are still there).  Could this potentially be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That GUID corresponds to "URL Path (FileRef)" field that is somehow missing, or incorrectly referenced in webpart.

If you export the CQWP and look at the .webpart XML, does it contain that field in QueryOverride, or in some other properties? If yes, see is it really needed and remove and reupload webpart.

Comment: When I export the CQWP, that particular field appears in a property named "DataMappings": `<property name="DataMappings" type="string">...|LinkUrl:{94f89715-e097-4e8b-ba79-ea02aa8b7adb},FileRef,Lookup;|...</property>`.  I'm not sure about just removing the offending line of code, since this affects all CQWPs, even brand new ones.  Should that field actually be missing, and if not - is there a way to check and/or get it back?

Comment: Verify that all required Site Collection and Site level features are activated. Looks like many of them are not as lot of columns etc. are missing.

Comment: Thanks Jussi Palo - I've just tried deactivating and then activating the "ctypes" feature and received the following error: `Enable-SPFeature : The content type with Id 0x defined in feature {695b6570-a48b-4a8e-8ea5-26ea7fc1d162} was found in the current site collection or in a subsite.`  It looks like the content types might be a bit muddled maybe?

Comment: You can fix that with heavy troubleshooting or recreating the site collection. I recommend the latter, unless you have content in the site collection that you cannot recreate or reimport.

Comment: Thanks Jussi Palo, I've decided to try and recreate the site collection as advised.  Troubleshooting may require too much effort and expertise which I don't possess.